# Are fcntl constants in Ubuntu different from other OS?

Tags: c

I found the problem with my `fcntl` implementation in js-ctypes. I was using the wrong constant values.

- Everywerhe I look though they have it different, For example:

  - https://github.com/search?p=4&q=%22define+F_RDLCK%22&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93
    [image: constants on github search of source code for fnctl constants]

These guys are getting 1 2 3 for `rdlck`, `wrlck`, and `unlck`.

- However when i run this C code to figure out the constnats on ubuntu its telling me they are 0, 1, and 2 :
  [image: my constants on ubuntu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that those constant values are Linux specific, not Ubuntu specific.

In your C file, you're getting `fcntl.h` from `/usr/include/fcntl.h` which contains:

```c
/* Get the definitions of O_*, F_*, FD_*: all the
   numbers and flag bits for `open', `fcntl', et al.  */
#include <bits/fcntl.h>
```

In `/usr/include/<your_arch>/bits/fcntl.h` you can see the following code:

```c
/* Include generic Linux declarations.  */
#include <bits/fcntl-linux.h>
```

Finally this `/usr/include/<your_arch>/bits/fcntl-linux.h` file defines those values as follow:

```c
#ifndef F_RDLCK
/* For posix fcntl() and `l_type' field of a `struct flock' for lockf().  */
# define F_RDLCK        0   /* Read lock.  */
# define F_WRLCK        1   /* Write lock.  */
# define F_UNLCK        2   /* Remove lock.  */
#endif
```

To confirm that it's not Ubuntu specific, you can check the definitions in the [libc source](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/fcntl-linux.h), they are the same.

Comment: I learned a ton from this post thank you! That's why I accepted this answer. I gave muru an up vote though. I'm very new to C thanks for this basic detail. So libc is used on linux'es right? Mac OS is based on linux but by "linu specific" this excludes mac os right?

Comment: Do you think the same applies for the order of fields in the `flock` structure? I tried to apply your technique to `flock` strcuture but not sure if I got it right. From my search `flock` field order differs on Mac OS based o nhere (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/fcntl.2.html) but im not sure if all linux have same field order.

Comment: @Noitidart: Sorry I can't confirm for OSX.

Comment: @Noitidart What do you mean by order of fields in the structure? The fields have names, the order is irrelevant. As a certified UNIX, OSX should have all the POSIX specified fields, and since Linux doesn't ditch compliance unless necessary, we would have those fields too.

Comment: Thanks muru man! Someone told me [HERE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17822233#17822233) that order mattered and it seemed to make a difference because im porting the structure to javascript. :(

Comment: @Noitidart that is a long chat, and I don't really get what you guys are doing. Are you setting up bindings for some C library in JS?

Comment: Yes sir, it's js-ctypes so I have to define the structure before I can use it. And the structure varies as verified by guy at mozilla [HERE](https://ask.mozilla.org/question/1134/order-of-strcuture-matters-test-case-flock-for-use-by-fcntl/?answer=1137#post-id-1137). I was wondering if you could help me show me how Sylvian looked up stuff, I would like to look up the constant values and structure for the os's of: freebsd, freebsd, and sunos please. The c libraries are `libc.so.7`, `libc.so.61.0`, and `libc.so`. Should I make seperate topic?

Answer (score 1):

The *value* of such constants are always implementation defined, unless the standards specify the value. If you use the values directly instead of the names, that's simply asking for trouble. Nothing in the `manpage` of [`fcntl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/fcntl) mentions the values, so assume nothing.

Comment: Thank you man! I will keep this in mind :) I learned a lot from @Sylvain's post so accepted but definitely definitely appreciate your post and upvoted it :)

Comment: @Noitidart Well, when I saw that answer I was pretty certain which one would get accepted. :D